# HDD makes a beep sound

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, overheating, ramdisk

My laptop has started to make a beep sound followed by a click. I checked the HDD health with multiple apps including the disk checking tool from Seagate which is my HDD manufacturer and it was ok. I also checked to see if its from my RAM but the RAM status was ok and my windows is able to see the RAM full size.

So what might be the problem? I was thinking its overheating but this morning it just made the sound 15 mins after I turned up the laptop and it wasn't warm at all.

Comment: If the harddisk clicks, it needs to realign the read/write head, which can have various reasons. You didn't tell us *how* you checked "hdd health with multiple apps", but what you need are the SMART values and the harddisk error log to see what has happened. If something else produced the clicks and not then harddisk, then it's something else ...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please [edit your post](//superuser.com/posts/1353665/edit) so it is not a "wall of text". Splitting it into paragraphs (by pressing `Enter` twice) makes it *much* easier to read. While you're at it, please use proper English ("i" should be "I"), and make sure all the sentences end with punctuation. You might also like to take the [Tour] and read the [Ask] page to better familiarise yourself with this site.

Answer (score 3):

Those sounds you describe really point to the hard drive since is the only moving part in your laptop (excluding fans). If you're sure about the sound coming from the hdd, check the BIOS for the SMART option and enable it if it's not already on. Then, find out the manufacturer (through the BIOS or your SO) then check their webpage and download (if possible, most of them have one) their own utility program to check it.

Anyway, you shouldn't keep important data on that hdd, I've seen many disk deaths starting like that. Good luck.

**EDIT**

@LPChip wrote on comments:

> It's worth pointing out that a harddisk failure can go undetected by software in the early stages because there's always a margin of error allowed before SMART technology will flag it as failing, and the SMART sensor itself may become defective too, in such way that the system doesn't realize the sensor is broken.

And he's really right.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a harddisk failure can go undetected by software in the early stages because there's always a margin of error allowed before SMART technology will flag it as failing, and the SMART sensor itself may become defective too, in such way that the system doesn't realize the sensor is broken.

Comment: You're right, thanks for your contribution. I'm going to edit my answer and quote your comment.

Comment: the thing is , it has been making this sound for last 6 month . i guess if hdd was about to die it should have been dead by now. im absolutely with out a clue now

Comment: The sound doesn't necessarily mean it's about to die in hours, but it definetely indicates that it's useful life is short by that point. Keep in mind that hard drives are precision machines and anything that's out of its running margins shows a fault, like an unusual sound while working. Again, you shouldn't keep important data on that drive.

Answer (score 0):

The sound you describe as a beep followed by a click could also be the harddrive doing repeated seek operations followed by resetting to its home position.  I experienced this years ago when my laptop's hard drive was starting to experience an increasing number of bad sectors before it finally just became unusable.

Comment: the thing is , it has been making this sound for last 6 month . i guess if hdd was about to die it should have been dead already

Comment: Not necessarily.  Years ago when it was happening to me, the HDD lasted for a very long time.  I didn't realize what was going on at the time, until it finally just stopped.  It did slow the computer down more and more over time.

Comment: I just switched to linux and it stopped making the sound any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by you switched to Linux?  You formatted your hard drive and installed Linux, or was Linux already setup as a dual boot?  If your problem is bad sectors and you didn't format or use chkdsk /f, then it's simply a matter of you are using a part of the disk that doesn't have the bad sectors which are the likely cause of the sound you've described.